# GAE: Modeling user Upvote/Downvote on entities

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I've read different docs on fan-out and big data modeling, but I'm still struggling to figure out how to properly model information that is contextual for a signed in user. Using reddit as an example, I'm trying to model the Upvote/Downvote of a post. So here are two of my entities:

```
class Score(ndb.Model):
   post = schema.KeyProperty(required=True)
   user = schema.KeyProperty(required=True)
   score_value = schema.IntegerProperty(default=0)

class Post(ndb.Model):
   # ... Other Properties ... #

   def fetch_score_async(self, user):
      self._score_query = Score.qry().filter(Score.post==self.key,
                                             Score.user==user.key).get_async()

   @property
   def user_score(self):
      ret = self._score_query.get_result()
      return ret.score_value if ret else 0
```

Then I iterate over the list of posts in my result and call `fetch_score_async`.

```
posts = Post.qry().filter(...).fetch_page(50)
for post in posts:
   post.fetch_score_async()
```

Lastly, I iterate the post list again and build up JSON. The theory here is that the scores will be fetched in parallel and my endpoint will be as fast as the post query plus the slowest score, rather than the sum of the scores.

But what's the right way to do this? This feels unconventional and wrong. I've seen people suggest using a tasklet and/or map/reduce approach, but in those cases they have keys and a one-to-one or a one-to-many hierarchy ([google dev guide](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/async#tasklets)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wanna use sharding.  There's some stuff about sharding in the GAE docs, I'm sure you can look it up for yourself.  Here's an example of a voting system designed for the GAE datastore:

http://eatdev.tumblr.com/post/15093224320/handling-user-ratings-on-app-engine

Comment: I might have misunderstood the article you posted, but I believe that sharding example was for calculating a vote count/average. The count it's self is not the problem I'm asking about. What I'm asking about is how to indicate to the logged in user, if they've upvoted or downvoted each post.

Comment: Yeah I totally misunderstood the question, the hard part is usually calculating the total score for the post. What you've done is pretty much the way to do it.  One change I would make is to create the key for the score from the post+user, in that case you don't have to query for it, you can just fetch by ID.  Otherwise the structure is fine.

Comment: Hey Dragonx, Thank you very much. I had that revelation last night. Creating a composite key means I can easily fetch (rather than query). And it gives memcache an opportunity to do it's job. Cheers.